# Grouping multile SQL results by a given field

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-schema

How can I group the results of the following query by employee?

OK so I have three tables:
1. company_employee which contains an employee id (company_employee.employee) mapped to a company id (company.id). it also contains an employee role

2. employee which contains employee first name, last name
3. company which contains an id, and a name

Right now I am retrieving all the employees with a certain role, but I get multiple entries for the same employee with a different company mapping. something like this:
My query is:

```
SELECT company_employee.employee, company_employee.company, employee.fname, employee.lname, company.name
 FROM company_employee
 JOIN employee on employee.id = company_employee.employee
 JOIN company on company.id = company_employee.company
 WHERE company_employee.role= 185;
```

My results are:

```
company_employee.employee     company_employee.company     employee.fname     employee.lname    company.name
111                           100                          John               Smith             Super Candy
111                           101                          John               Smith             Red Ballons
222                           102                          Kevin              Lora              Super Computers
111                           103                          John               Smith             Star Events
222                           104                          Kevin              Lora              Vintage Pencils
333                           105                          Margarett          Bush              Top Security
```

What I want to get is a listing of this sort:

```
Employee 111 John Smith mapped to a list of companies (100, 101, 103)
Employee 222 Kevin Lora mapped to a list of companies (102, 104)
Employee 333 Margarett Bush mapped to a list of companies (105)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the exact result you're trying get for this data?

Comment: I don't want to put actual customer data here. I don't want to end up with multiple employee entries. I want an entry per employee, but each entry containing a list of their associated companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function:

```
SELECT   company_employee.employee, employee.fname, employee.lname, 
         LISTAGG(company_employee.company) 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY company_employee.company),
         LISTAGG(company.name) 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY company_employee.company),
FROM     company_employee
JOIN     employee ON employee.id = company_employee.employee
JOIN     company ON company.id = company_employee.company
WHERE    company_employee.role = 185
GROUP BY company_employee.employee, employee.fname, employee.lname
```